# AJAX DE CONSULTA DE DATOS A API REST

Tags: php, ajax

Estimados por favor su ayuda.
Estoy desarrollando una app que busca personas en una api rest y me presenta de cada persona una tabla,
hasta ahí lo tengo todo controlado, sin embargo necesito que al dar click en un botón asociado a cada tabla envíe el id de esa persona a un nuevo ajax, el resto de registros se oculten y se quede la persona seleccionada mas los datos adicionales traídos por el botón.
He intentado pasar la nueva variable pero solo me pasa el primer registro de las tablas,

Ejemplo

Consulto un dato por apellido genero N tablas por cada registro que encuentre coincidencia pero al dar click en el botón que pueden ver que genero solo me envía el dato de la primera tabla generada no funciona el mismo botón del resto de tablas.

Gracias de antemano su ayuda

Mil disculpas si en un inicio plateé mal la pregunta

[image: Eso es mi código, como ven ya genero la tabla de los primeros resultados y ahi en el template genero un botón para llamar a otra consulta]

Comment: Sin el código que has hecho hasta ahora, lo que intentaste para hacer el nuevo llamado y la estructura de lo que deseas ocultar, es difícil que recibas ayuda. Por favor añade esta información relevante a tu pregunta.

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Mil disculpas si planteé mal la pregunta, la acabo de corregir